# Force dynamic binding

Tags: java, maven

## Problem

I'm refactoring/porting an application that uses an external API that has two versions, lets call them *API 1.0* and *API 2.0*.
It was using *API 2.0* but it was decided that it should support *API 1.0* without having to compile two separate applications.

*API 2.0* is (almost) the same as 1.0 but with extra methods.
I configured my maven POM to use *API 1.0* as a dependency and fixed (using the compatible API) all compile errors that appeared

I'm however facing the following issue:
When compiling with *API 2.0* it runs well on:

- *API 2.0*
- *API 1.0*

However when compiling with *API 1.0* it only runs well on *API 1.0* and throws NoSuchMethodException on *API 2.0*.

I tracked the issue and is being show in the following code:

**Usage**

```
import test.A;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.sayHello();
    }
}
```

**API 1.0**

```
package test;

public class A {
    public A sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from API 1.0");
        return this;
    }
}
```

**API 2.0**

```
package test;

public class A extends B<A> {}

class B<T> {
    public T sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from API 2.0");
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

Compiling and running them on

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)
```

The method is there, however it seems that is expecting A sayHello() instead of T sayHello(). Even though that T is actually A.
For what i understand it seems like a static vs dynamic binding issue.

## Question

Is there a way preserve API 1.0 as my dependency?

It works well for spotting errors before runtime. So forcing dynamic binding or use API 1.0 as a dependency but compile with API 2.0 or something along those lines would be useful for me.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only choose one of the two APIs since there would be no way to distinguish between using API 1 or API 2 methods.

NoSuchMethodException indicates that some method is required and can not find it.

You may be able to use reflection to compile and run the API that is available.

Comment: I'm aware of the NoSuchMethodException. The API is sort of available.The problem I'm facing is that if i set API 2.0 i won't see compile time errors when using non-available methods on API 1.0. If I set  API 1.0 I get to see when I'm using a API 2.0-only method, but i get the NoSuchMethodException (see sample codes to see what i mean, sample compiles well with both API's but throws NoSuchMethodException if compiled with API 1.0 and ran with API 2.0. I'm looking for a way to alert me when using API that is not available on API 1.0.

Comment: @Josejulio `The problem I'm facing is that if i set API 2.0 i won't see compile time errors when using non-available methods on API 1.0` this is basicly not possible. The only explanation is that you are usinig different library on compile time and on runtime.

Comment: @Antoniossss could you please read the question? I'm indeed using different library on compile time and on runtime.

Comment: @Josejulio assuming that your description is right, method signature will differ in both cases due to type erasure. So in 1.0 API method is `public A sayHello()` but in 2.0 API it will be `public Object sayHello()` and those are not compatible thus mentioned exception. You can tear down A to Object, but not the other way around - that is why it works like u described.

Comment: I indeed had to use reflection to run the method. As @Antoniossss said, the method signatures were not compatible on runtime.